# Unable to getaddrinfo for AWS SDK Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Following the documentation for Lambda on [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listFunctions-property). This is the code to get a list of lambda functions.

```
var params = {
    };

lambda.listFunctions(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

When I run this code, I got the following error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND lambda.us-east-1
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26) {
  message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND lambda.us-east-1',
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'lambda.us-east-1',
  region: 'us-east-1\t',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2020-05-04T04:17:48.184Z
} Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND lambda.us-east-1
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26)
```

`lambda.us-east-1` seems to be wrong and it should be `lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. Is there an additional config I have to do?

Comment: `region: 'us-east-1\t',` seems very suspicious, suggesting there may be a copy/paste error in part of the code that you didn't show -- the constructor call that creates the `lambda` object, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your missing out few things in your code:

Try out below:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda()

var params = {
    };

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
lambda.listFunctions(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
})};
```

[image: Output Results]